# Função que retorne próximo caracter na tabela ASCII em PHP

Tags: php, string, char, ascii

Eu gostaria de fazer uma função em PHP que recebesse um caracter e retornasse o próximo caracter, de acordo com a tabela ASCII.

Por exemplo: recebe 'a' e retorna 'b'. Eu sei fazer isso em C, que seria

```
char funcao(char C) {
  return C++;
}
```

Porém dessa maneira não dá certo em PHP. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: E se a letra de entrada for `z`, a saída deve ser `}`?

Comment: Sim, de acordo com a tabela ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta converter o valor para inteiro com a função `ord()`, incrementar o valor desejado e converter para *string* novamente com a função `chr()`.

```
function charOffset(string $char, int $offset = 3): string
{
    return chr(ord($char) + $offset);
}
```

Assim, basta chamar a função:

```
echo charOffset('a');  // 'd'
echo charOffset('f', 10);  // 'p'
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GroundedSociableSecurity) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ACogud)</sup>

Comment: Deu certinho aqui, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Veja se é isso que quer.

```
<?php

$a = ord("a"); #pega o dec de "a"

function transform($transform)
{
    $otro = $transform + 3; #adiciona +3 ao inteiro de $transform
    var_dump(chr($otro));   #mostra na tela o dec de 100 "d"
}

transform($a);
```